# catch does not exist in type subscription

Tags: angular

catch does not exist in type subscription in angular4.

```js
this.route.parent.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        const etc = this.service.getEtc()
        Observable.blah.subscribe(results => {
          this.abc = false
        })
          .catch( err => {
            this.service.showErrorAlert('can not find');
          })
    });
```

Comment: the return of method subscribe() isn't a Observable... it's an subscription object, with methods like dispose()

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Just wonder if you have any idea how to remove this error.

Comment: are you using rxjs? try importing the catch operator `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the `subscribe` method returns a subscription, and should usually be the last call in your chain. Try:

```ts
Observable.blah
  .catch(err => this.service.showErrorAlert('can not find'))
  .subscribe(results => this.abc = false);
```

### Updated for RXJS 6:

With the introduction of the pipe operator the above code can be replaced verbatim with the following:

```ts
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Observable.blah
  .pipe(catchError(err => this.service.showErrorAlert('can not find')))
  .subscribe(results => this.abc = false);
```

However `catchError` is supposed to be used for error recovery somewhere in the pipeline, for example: there has been an error but you have a default object you can return instead.

To catch an error at the end of the observable chain I would recommend using a different `.subscribe` overload and passing in an error handler.

```ts
Observable.blah
  .subscribe(
    results => this.abc = false,
    err => this.service.showErrorAlert('can not find')
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to call catch of your subscribe. That is not possible. You have 2 options:

1:

```
Observable.blah
    .catch(err => {...})
    .subscribe(results => {
        this.abc = false
    })
```

2:

```
Observable.blah
    .subscribe(results => {
        this.abc = false
    },
    err => {
        ...
    })
```